# How to clear transaction memory using either SQL or PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, deadlock

I have an application that is live in a multiuser environment.

I have a problem when two or more people call SQL stored procs at the same time (`SELECT` and `INSERT`).

The memory on the server maxes out and a deadlock error is returned:

```
'(0=> 4000 1=>1205 2=> Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another
process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim)
```

I'm positive that this is due to the memory not being cleared after each transaction.

My code looks like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE table ...
    SELECT column FROM table_2 ...
    EXEC dbo.stored_proc
COMMIT
```

The stored procedures themselves do not have `COMMIT`.

I've read about `mssql_free_statement()` but I need either a SQL or PHP PDO alternative.

Also, is my diagnosis correct or could there be something else causing the deadlock?

Comment: After the sql stored procs has ended i think the memory will be freed. So maybe it has to do to other things

Comment: are the sprocs `commit`ing the transactions they're working on? That would "clear" the memory. If they're not, and they're locking things in different orders, then you WILL get deadlocks and can't do anything about it without reorganizing your code.

Comment: You can run a trace and find the queries involved in the deadlock

Comment: My SQL statements are wrapped in a `BEGIN TRANSACTION ... COMMIT` and the procs are being called in those blocks, but the procs themselves do not have `COMMIT`.

Comment: Would using `WITH (NOLOCK)` do some good?

Comment: You need to run a trace an capture the deadlock graph.  Until then we are all just speculating on what is actually causing the deadlock.